# Is "build" concept applicable to interpreted languages? In which way?

Tags: build, continuous-integration

I'm describing a Continuous Integration process for several PHP projects, and I'm wondering if "build" concept could be applicable (and how, if possible) in a correct way.

In compiled languages, such as C, the "build" concept is quite obvious: the compiled executable.

But with interpreted languages, e.g. PHP or JavaScript, where there is no binary, and the "only" thing you have is the source code, how can be (if possible) this concept applied? Which would be an example of a PHP (or any other interpreted languagte) app build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can have builds with interpreted languages. There are many, many build systems for projects using interpreted languages.

A build is essentially an instance of your source code in action, and getting that source code activate requires some process. For JavaScript, you might have to concatenate all of your source files together, then minify them, then open up a browser, and then open your app to 'build' your software.

Thus, the 'build' of software written in interpreted languages is the process by which you convert your inert source code into a running instance on your machine.